# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 591: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code to convert docx files to pure text:

```
import docx
import glob

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

for file in glob.glob('*.docx'):
    outfile = open(file.replace('.docx', '-out.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf8')


for line in open(file):
    print(getText(filename), end='', file=outfile)
outfile.close()
```

However, when I execute it, there is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\add spaces docx\converting docx to pure text.py", line 16, in <module>
    for line in open(file):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 591: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error that you print does not come from the code you posted. The line `for line in open(file):` is missing. Please post a complete, reproducable example.

Comment: Edited to post the complete, reproducible code.

Answer (score -1):

Although I do not know the [docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) modules as much, I think I can find a solution.

According to [fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/), the [Unicode character 8f](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8f/index.htm) (which is what the charmap codec couldn't decode, resulting in a [UnicodeDecodeError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError)) is a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters).

You should be aware that when [reading files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) (which seems to be the case for what the docx module is doing), you should be aware of control characters, because sometimes [Python](https://www.python.org/) can't decode it.

The solution to this is to give up on the docx module, learn how [.docx](https://www.howtogeek.com/304622/what-is-a-.docx-file-and-how-is-it-different-from-a-.doc-file-in-microsoft-word/) files work and are formatted, and when you read a docx file, use `open(filename, "rb")` so Python will be able to decode it.

However, this might not be the problem. As you can see, in the directory encodings, it uses cp1512 as it's encoding (default) instead of utf-8. Try changing it to utf_8.py (for me it comes up as utf_8.pyc).

**NOTE:** Sorry for the lack of links. This is because I do not have higher than 10 reputation (because I am new to Stack Overflow).

Comment: How can I write the code lines to change it from the default encoding cp1512 to utf8?

Comment: I think you can use `.encode("utf-8")` when reading a file in mode rb. However, with the docx module, I do not know what to do. My suggestion is to check the docx code (and maybe if there is a setup file, check that too) for anything relating to the encoding from bytes to a string, and change that from cp1512 to utf-8.

Comment: Thank you and I will try that suggestion.